# Fill chart with listBox

Tags: c#, charts, listbox

I want the values of my listbox shown in a chart.

I know that I can set the XY Values like this:

```
this.chart1.Series["HT"].Points.AddXY("", "");
```

How can I get the Data from my listbox? For example the x values from listBox1 and y values from listBox2.

Thank you,
Thomas

Comment: What have you tried? Please share you code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    this.chart1.Series["HT"].Points.AddXY(listBox1.Items[i], listBox2.Items[i]);
}
```

Requirements:
Both ListBoxes have the same item count and the item type has the right type for the point.

Comment: works just as I wanted it to work. Thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome. Please note that this was only an example. If listbox2 has less items then listbox1 there will be an exception.

Comment: Okay, but in my case both listboxes allways have the same amount of items, so it just works perfect.